# Proofreading there is degree of divisor polynomial is less or equal to $n/2$

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, proof-verification, solution-verification

Given a degree $n$, reducible polynomial $f(x)$ over a field $\mathbb{K}$, prove there is less or equal $n\over 2$ degree divisor polynomial,

My current proof:
$$\text{Assume the statement is false, imply all the degree of divisor polynomials are greater than n/2}$$
$$\text{Let all the divisors of the polynomial are }P_{1}(x)P_{2}(x)\ldots P_{k}(x)=f(x)$$
$$\Rightarrow \deg(P_{1}(x)) + \deg(P_{2}(x)) + \ldots + \deg(P_{k}(x)) > \deg(f(x))=n$$
$$\text{This contradicts }$$ 
$$\text{if} \quad g(x)h(x) = f(x)\text{ then }\quad \deg(g(x))+\deg(h(x)) = \deg(f(x))$$

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is correct.

Since you don't need to divide the polynomial to irreducible factors, it is enough to say that

> Since $f$ is reducible, we can write $f=gh$. By the indirect assumption, we would have $\deg(g),\,\deg(h)>n/2$ which already contradicts
>   $$n=\deg(f)=\deg(g)+\deg(h)\,.$$

Comment: Thanks to simplify my proof